# macro expansion in g++ and clang++

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-optimization, clang++

```
#include <iostream>
#define DOUBLE1(x) x + x
#define DOUBLE2(x) 2 * x
int main() {
    int a = 2;
    std::cout << DOUBLE2(a++) << " " << DOUBLE1(++a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << a;
}
```

The execution of this program prints `4 9 5` in `clang++` and `4 10 5` in `g++`.
I'm confused on how the operation precedence is taking place.

Note:
I didn't write this code this was a asked as a `predict output question` in a course.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the value returned in such a statement. Just don't write code like this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior) - _The order of evaluation of the operands is unspecified_

Comment: *Note: I didn't write this code this was a asked as a predict output question in a course* -- What a complete waste of a student's time to ask them a question like this.  No sane C++ programmer writes code this way.  A good C++ course would just state right away that the behavior is undefined, and never write code in this manner.

Comment: To follow on from what Paul said, you cannot possibly predict the outcome of such an operation... See the second answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/what-are-sequence-points-and-how-do-they-relate-to-undefined-behavior

Comment: What was the answer the "course" gave you?  Was one of the choices "the behavior is undefined"?

Comment: Just don't use macros for this, use functions. Also try to keep the number of side effects limited to one per line (evaluation order is not specified) and it is easier to debug.

Comment: Did you pay for the course?  Demand your money back.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/4Pb1Y1Wen `multiple unsequenced modifications to 'a'` `operation on 'a' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]`

Comment: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-macros2

Comment: I'm new to programming btw Don't much about standards and best practices.
Any suggestion on good books to read on this topic ?

Comment: Some good resources to learn C++ from are [learncpp.com](https://www.learncpp.com/) for your initial steps (it is very decent for an online tutorial). 
Then use [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) to lookup everything C++ has to offer. 
And finally use [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to keep up to date with how C++ currently is intended to be used,
C++ keeps evolving and "better" approaches are added with each new version.

Comment: Even if you assume right to left, then none of those answers are correct. If you do `++a + ++a` first, and again going right to left, then you get `4 + 3`, which of course is `7`. Then when `DOUBLE2` gets run, you have `4*2` which is `8`. So the output (since presumably output would still be in order), you get `8 7` ... which is not an option in your list ... This is a government certified course? Or you've made changes to what they wrote and changed the meaning unintentionally.

Comment: I'm so sorry I have confused you,
Consider right to left execution when `cout << DOUBLE1(a++) << DOUBLE2(a++);`
So i modified the `cout `.
**The code actually called with** `a++` **passed to both calls not** `++a`
My point is if the behaviour of the program is undefined `multiple unsequenced modifications to 'a' operation on 'a' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]`
How do I pick an option ?

Comment: I changed the Meaning Unintentionally. **So Sorry**.

Comment: C++ leaves a lot to the discretion of the implementor of the compiler so that the language can support a wide variety of targets (hardware and support software) and allow the optimization that C++ is famous for. The result is a lot of boobytraps for the unaware. [Here are some of the macro boobytraps](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/style-and-techniques#why-not-macros).

Answer (score 0):

Your course should have taught you something like this :

```
#include <iostream>

// Macros are a last resort 
// and usually only used when
// you need to concatenate some strings to 
// make new lines of code
//#define DOUBLE1(x) x + x
//#define DOUBLE2(x) 2 * x

int double1(int a)
{
    return a+a;
}

int double2(int a)
{
    return 2*a;
}

int main() {
    int a = 2;
    
    // epxlicitly model evaluation order
    // the compiler will not care you write
    // extra lines. It will still create
    // good (optimized) assembly code.
    // and at least now you can set breakpoints
    // to check what your code is doing in a debugger
    int a2 = double2(a);
    a++;
    ++a;
    int a3 = double1(a);
        
    std::cout << a2 << " " << a3 << "\n"; //std::endl; only use endl when you need to flush
    std::cout << a;
}
```

Comment: What is your point? Please read comments under a question.

Comment: My point is the code shown in the course has NO answer. The result cannot be predicted (as you state) the evaluation order is undefined.

Comment: It's not just unspecified, the behaviour of the whole program is undefined since you have unsequenced modification of the *same* variable when `DOUBLE1` expands to `a++ + a++`.  [Is int a = ++i + ++i undefined behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61264384) uses pre-increment `++i + ++i` as an example, but the same reasoning applies to `a++ + a++` post-increment.  If they were "indeterminately sequenced", the compiler would have to pick one order but couldn't overlap evaluation of the operands.  But evaluation of operands for `+` is fully unsequenced, they can overlap.